# why Fiddler is not capturing traffic when I turn my pc into a wi-fi server?

Tags: android, wifi, fiddler

I've connected my Android device to my PC wi-fi using an application called Connectify , which make it easier to browse the internet using PC'S internet connection , when I did make connection to a web server using my android device , Fiddler didn't capture the traffic .

I am using windows 7

Routing my Android Wi-Fi connection to a proxy doesn't work , my router redirects all requests from local network to the Log in page to the router settings

Answer (score 2):

To monitor the network traffic of an Android device using fiddler

1. Open Fiddler on your pc
2. Go to Tools >Fiddler Options >Connections. Make sure 'Allow remote computers to connect' is checked'.
3. In your android device, go to your wifi settings, long press on your current Wifi and click on 'Modify network'
4. Click 'Advanced Options' and set proxy to manual.
5. Under 'proxy hostname', enter the local IP of your computer.Under 'proxy port', type '8888' (this is the default port that fiddler listens on)

Now, you should be able to see the Android network traffic on your fiddler.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not use the Connectify. Uninstall it.

Follow the exact instructions on the fiddler documentation. It has screenshots for [setting up the proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) and everything.

Make sure that your PC shares its internet connection when you first connect it to your wifi network.

Do not attempt this at a coffee shop or in an hotel, where wifi isolation is often practiced as a security measure.

It goes without saying, do not forget to turn off the mobile data of your android device.